# How to add a filter based on more conditions in a report in Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report with one existing filter. Now I am trying to add additional 2 filters but each of them have multiple conditions and here I am getting lost.
(I am using Report Builder 2016.)

1. Filter to be added

field `Content` LIKE ('%Tax%') AND field `DeliveryDate` in current Month

2. Filter to be added

field `RTI` = 'No' AND field `ActulDelivery` = 'Null' AND field`ScheduledDeliveryDate` from previous months (excluding current month)

My existing filter says: show every shipment that has `FinalDeliveryDate` in current month.
The value of the filter looks like this:

=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddDays(-1)

The new 2 filters should exclude all shipments with the conditions mentioned above.

Please could anybody advise me how to deal with it? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: are your filters 1 and 2 based on some condition i.e IF condition A is satisfied add filter 1 else Filter 2.
If yes what is that condition?

Comment: No, there is no condition like this. Basically, I just need to get rid off all data sets (shipments) that are fulfilling conditions in filter 1 and 2.

Comment: What does your query look like from SQL Server? Why don't you handle the exclusions from the source query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add Filter as shown below in Diagram.
Note Ignore Last filter in Screenshot rather check the Expressin and value for For ActulDelivery = 'Null'.

Also filter for ScheduledDeliveryDate from previous months (excluding current month) is not created by me but you got an Idea how to achieve this. Try step by step. try adding one filter at a time and then you can combine all of them

[image]

For Content Value expression is goin to be. * is % in SSRS

```
="*abcd*"
```

For DeliveryDate in current Month

```
=Month(Fields!DeliveryDate .Value)
```

and Value expression will be

```
=Month(now)
```

For field RTI = 'No'

Value expression is

```
="NO"
```

For ActulDelivery = 'Null'

Expression is "true"

and Value is,

```
=IIF(Isnothing(Fields!user_name.Value),"true","false")
```

Comment: Should probably have the year incorporated into there somewhere - either add one or change the MONTH to `FORMAT(X, "yyyyMM")`

Comment: Sure but where exactly you mean ??

Comment: Either add another filter for the Delivery Date that uses YEAR functions like you have with MONTH (`=YEAR(Fields!DeliveryDate.Value)` and `=YEAR(NOW)`). Or use the FORMAT function to compare both in one filter (`=FORMAT(Fields!DeliveryDate.Value, "yyyyMM")` and `=FORMAT(NOW, "yyyyMM")` `) like you're doing with MONTHt.